# Generate a key column based on first ID row value for duplicate values

Tags: sql-server

I have the below table and need to generate a new key for duplicate values based on first ID row.

| ID | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Alex | CA |
| 1002 | Alex | CA |
| 1003 | Smith | WV |
| 1004 | Smith | WV |

Below is what I need to end up with.

| Key | ID | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1001 | Alex | CA |
| 1001 | 1002 | Alex | CA |
| 1003 | 1003 | Smith | WV |
| 1003 | 1004 | Smith | WV |

Comment: Which fields should be checked for duplicity? Is it name and state only?

Comment: yes, name and state.

Comment: Why don’t you just add a new colum auto incremented, since all your id’s will be changed (as shown in your example).

Comment: yes, auto incremental id makes it easier, but we have a requirement to apply the first ID as key for duplicate rows.

Comment: Try: select MIN(id) over(partition by Name, State) AS [Key], * from yourtable

Comment: Thanks a lot siggemannen for your quick help. this solves my requirement.